# Django save() is not saving form to database

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller

Hello I have problem with saving forms to database. When I try to save the **AdHistoryForm** in **ads_history_add** view the forim is rendered correctly but after submitting nothing happens aside of redirecting me to **ads_history_list** view.

In addition when I try to submit this form with empty field it doesnt show any errors (I included them in template), so maybe it is validation thing.

When I try to add **Ad** in **ads_add** view everything is ok.

Can you help me?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Ad(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name=_("name"), help_text=_("required"), unique=True)
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("content"), blank=True)
    url = models.URLField(verbose_name=_("website"), blank=True)
    date_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modify = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class AdHistory(models.Model):
    ad = models.ForeignKey(Ad)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    comment = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("comment"), help_text=_("required"))
    date_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modify = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.comment
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Ad, AdHistory


class AdForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ad
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'url']


class AdHistoryForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta:
        model = AdHistory
        fields = ['comment']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, user_passes_test
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

from .models import Ad, AdHistory
from .forms import AdForm, AdHistoryForm   



@login_required
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def ads_list(request):
    ads_list = Ad.objects.all().order_by('-date_modify')
    context = {'list': ads_list}
    return render(request, 'ads_list.html', context)

@login_required
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def ads_add(request):
    form = AdForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('ads_list')
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'ads_form_add.html', context)

@login_required
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def ads_history_list(request, ad_id):
    ad = get_object_or_404(Ad, pk=ad_id)
    history_list = AdHistory.objects.select_related().filter(ad=ad).order_by('-id')
    context = {'list': history_list, 'object': ad}
    return render(request, 'ads_history_list.html', context)

@login_required
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def ads_history_add(request, ad_id):
    ad = get_object_or_404(Ad, pk=ad_id)
    f = AdHistoryForm(request.POST or None)
    if f.is_valid():
        new_entry = f.save(commit=False)
        new_entry.ad = ad
        new_entry.user = request.user
        new_entry.save()
        return redirect('ads_history_list', ad_id)
    context = {'form': f, 'object': ad}
    return render(request, 'ads_history_add.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
rom django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from ads import views

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', views.ads_list, name="ads_list"),
    url(r'^add/', views.ads_add, name="ads_add"),
    url(r'^(?P<ad_id>\d+)/history/$', views.ads_history_list, name="ads_history_list"),
    url(r'^(?P<ad_id>\d+)/history/add$', views.ads_history_add, name="ads_history_add"),
)
```

both form templates inherits from this template:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action=".">

    {% csrf_token %} 

    <table class="table table-bordered crm-form">

        {% for field in form.visible_fields %} 

        <tr>
            <th>
                {{ field.label }}
            </th>
            <td>
                {{ field }}

                <small>{{ field.help_text }}</small>

                {% if field.errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">{{ field.errors }}</div>
                {% endif %}

            </td>

        </tr>

        {% endfor %}
    </table>

     <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success crm-float-right">
        {% trans 'Save' %}
    </button>

</form>
```

Comment: Which form? You have a couple of them...

Comment: I mean AdHistoryForm, thanks :). Already updated question.

Comment: It seems fine. Are you sure you didn't mess up form's `action` attribute? Maybe you just go directly to `ads_history_list`, never requesting `ads_history_add`?

Comment: I am using action="." because I'am posting the form through the same view that render it. I can add Ad model normally through the same template, but AdHistory isnt saved .

Comment: This can't be your real code. You never pass the form to the template in either view, so no fields would ever be displayed.

Comment: Ah yes Daniel, you're of course right, I removed context variable from view to clear things out, I add them back immediately.

Comment: You replace `request.POST` with `None` when it is empty, that is why you don't get errors (form is unbound). You have to check `request.method == 'POST'` explicitly, like `f = AdHistoryForm(request.POST if request.method == 'POST' else None)`.

Comment: @Frax make that an answer bud.

Comment: I try this one but still no errors on empty form. More, I changed 
return redirect('ads_history_list', ad_id) to return redirect('ads_list') and it still redirect to ads_history_list, so if f.is_valid(): doesnt return true

Comment: @Robert Grant That's one-line answer to additional problem, not even mensioned in original question - I don't think it is worth an answer.

Comment: @damogari Well, turns out I was quite right with bad `action` suspicion. Note for future - in such cases, first try to determine which code is exactly runned. First, see in server log or browser, what urls were requested, than try adding `print` statements or something similar in views' code to check what is actually executed. That would had quickly shown that your view were never really used.

Comment: @Frax Yes, definitely I must keep more attention to test everything before asking for help. Thank you for your support :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The POST request never reaches your `ads_history_add` view because your `ads_history_add` URL pattern does not have a trailing slash. Without the trailing slash, `action="."` in the `ads_form_add.html` template results in a POST to `(?P<ad_id>\d+)/history/`

Add the trailing slash and everything should work as expected. Alternatively, you could omit the `action` attribute to tell the browser to POST to the current URL.

Also note that, although not relevant here, it is probably a good habit to display `{{ form.non_field_errors }}`.

Comment: You could also note, that using `""` instead of `"."` wouldn't have this problem (and would more accurately express the intension of requesting exactly the same url).

Comment: @Frax that would generally work, but is actually not valid HTML5, see http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-action. Alternatively, one could omit the action altogether, I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @DanielHepper Thanks for pointing that out. I leaned to use `action=""` quite a time ago from some example but were never aware of actual standards. I feel enlightened now ;)